# Cauchy Problem (PDE)

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

> Find the solution to the Cauchy data problem
>
> $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} − u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = −2u$$
>
> where $u(x, 0) = x$.

I know how to solve homogeneous Cauchy problems. However, I am struggling to understand non-homogeneous equations like this one. Can somebody please give a detailed solution?

Comment: oh, as an additional (somewhat pedantic) note, this is not a linear pde. It is a quasilinear pde. I removed the tag for linear pde

Comment: Why did you delete your other post on $u_{xx} + u - u^3 =0$?  Did you find the answer?  I thought it was a nice question, I was going to answer it! Cheers!

Comment: I believe i figured it out on my own thanks , i'l repost it though for any others that may want to reference it, If you have free time could you possibly help me with this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2712649/stability-analysis-pde, im really struggling with the addition of the harvest term

Comment: @RobertLewis I reposted the old question with my solution

Comment: OK, so the re-posted question is the same as the old one, right?  I don't see the "harvest term".

Comment: @RobertLewis My bad I sent the wrong Link,here is the proper one, any help you could provide me with would be greatly appreciated! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2712713/stability-theoryperturbations

Comment: I checked it out but would you mind fixing the $\LaTeX$?  it's hard to read . . .

Comment: @RobertLewis Will do

Comment: @RobertLewis Fixed the notation, sorry for the wait had to google how to do it

Answer (score 5):

By characteristics, examining the pde along a curve $U(t)=u(x(t),t)$ where
$$
x'(t)=-U(t)\\
U'(t)=-2U(t)
$$
solving the second, we find 
$$
U(t)=U_0e^{-2t}
$$
and setting initial conditions to be $x_0=x(0)$ and using the Cauchy data 
$$
U(0)=x_0
$$
we have
$$
U(t)=x_0e^{-2t}
$$
giving 
$$
x'(t)=-x_0e^{-2t}\implies x=x_0(\frac{1}{2}e^{-2t}+\frac{1}{2})
$$
and solving for $x_0$ and plugging in the expression for $U(t)$ we find
$$
U(t)=u(x,t)=e^{-2t}\frac{x}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-2t}}=\frac{2x}{e^{2t}+1}
$$

Comment: thank you for your work, When i was attempting the solution i got 3 partial derivatives. dx/ds= -u, dt=ds=1, du/ds=-2u, then i tried to parameterize them and solve, I was just wondering why you were able to do only using 2 derivatives?

Comment: If you want to use an auxiliary variable $s$ for the curve $(x(s),t(s))$ you'll find immediately $t'(s)=1\implies t=s$ since we want initial condition $t(0)=0$. I suppressed this in my solution to streamline things

Comment: ok thank you for the clarification and the help!

Comment: @steve no problem!

Comment: The solution for $x$ should be $x(t)=x_0(\frac12(e^{-2t}-1)+1)=\frac12(e^{-2t}+1)x_0$, this should correct the problem.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} − u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = −2u$$

System of characteristic ODEs : $\quad \frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{-u}=\frac{du}{-2u}$

A first family of characteristic curves comes from $\quad \frac{dx}{-u}=\frac{du}{-2u} \quad\to\quad du-2dx=0$
$$u-2x=c_1$$

A second family of characteristic curves comes from $\quad \frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{-2u} \quad\to\quad \ln|u|=-2t+$constant.
$$e^{2t}u=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE is obtained on the form of implicit equation :
$$\Phi\left((u-2x)\:,\:(e^{2t}u) \right)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary function of two variables, to be determined according to the initial condition.

Or equivalently :
$$u-2x=F(e^{2t}u)$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function, to be determined according to the initial condition.

CONDITION : $\quad u(x,0)=x$ to be put into the above general solution.
$$x-2x=F(e^{2(0)}x) \quad\to\quad F(x)=-x$$
So, the function $F$ is determined : $\quad F(X)=-X\quad$ any $X$.

Putting it into the above general solution where $\quad X=e^{2t}u\quad$ leads to :
$$u-2x=-(e^{2t}u)$$
$$u=\frac{2x}{1+e^{2t}}$$